# I am trying to feed data from TFRecords to AlexNet and I am getting this error

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning

OutOfRangeError (see above for traceback): FIFOQueue '_0_batch/fifo_queue' is closed and has insufficient elements (requested 560, current size 0)
     [[Node: batch = QueueDequeueManyV2[component_types=[DT_UINT8, DT_INT32], timeout_ms=-1, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](batch/fifo_queue, batch/n)]]

Comment: you're not accessing your file TFRecords file. sharing the code may be helpful

Comment: ok i will share it